# Android: Call activity method from view extended class

Tags: android, view, methods, android-activity, call

I've got two classes:

- `MenuActivity` - "blank" activity, which loads layout with view as control from palette.
- `MenuView` - class extended with View, its put into `layout` as control from palette.

In `MenuView` I have `handler` for touching screen, and I want to change activity after this action, the answer is: how to call method in activity from view class, if this class is putted as control on layout?

Answer (score 0):

Usually this is done  via listener pattern  - your activity registers itself ( or anonymous inner class )  to your custom view, and then view calls some custom method on listener.